# Application not able to connect to smtp host and port 587 using docker

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

I am new to docker. I need your help in resolving one of the docker issue which I am facing for past 1 week. I have a Spring Boot application which connects to a company email server using SMTP host and SMTP port to send out emails. The application is working fine when it is working as a normal java program locally. Application is able to establish a connection to SMTP server and able to send out emails. Now, as soon as the application is on docker container, I am getting “connection timed out” error.

Please note that I am able to send out curl commands like google.com from docker container just to check if I am able to connect to the internet or not and was able to get the response there. I am not sure what could go wrong as curl is working for HTTP but SMTP connection is not working on docker container. Do I need to change anything to docker settings?

I have also tried making the /etc/hosts file and /etc/resolve.conf at par with the host configuration file but still not able to proceed ahead. I am using mac so I thought that the error might have come because of the settings of thin layer VM that docker for mac creates, so I tried running the application on linux machine, but still got no success.

Any suggestions or pointers would be highly appreciated.

The error stack trace:

```
notification-service        | Caused by: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.company.com, 587; timeout 10000
notification-service        |   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2209) ~[javax.mail-1.6.1.jar!/:1.6.1]
notification-service        |   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:740) ~[javax.mail-1.6.1.jar!/:1.6.1]
notification-service        |   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366) ~[javax.mail-1.6.1.jar!/:1.6.1]
notification-service        |   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246) ~[javax.mail-1.6.1.jar!/:1.6.1]
notification-service        |   at com.company.EmailSender.sendEmailNotification(EmailSender.java:127) ~[classes!/:na]
notification-service        |   ... 38 common frames omitted
notification-service        | Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
notification-service        |   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
notification-service        |   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
notification-service        |   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
notification-service        |   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
notification-service        |   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
notification-service        |   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
notification-service        |   at com.sun.mail.util.WriteTimeoutSocket.connect(WriteTimeoutSocket.java:115) ~[javax.mail-1.6.1.jar!/:1.6.1]
notification-service        |   at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:351) ~[javax.mail-1.6.1.jar!/:1.6.1]
notification-service        |   at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:239) ~[javax.mail-1.6.1.jar!/:1.6.1]
notification-service        |   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2175) ~[javax.mail-1.6.1.jar!/:1.6.1]
notification-service        |   ... 42 common frames omitted
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM com.company/serverjre:8

ARG JAR_FILE
ARG JAR_INSTRUMENT

VOLUME /tmp
COPY ${JAR_FILE} /app.jar
COPY ${JAR_INSTRUMENT} /spring-instrument.jar

EXPOSE 9000

ENTRYPOINT exec java -javaagent:/spring-instrument.jar -Duser.timezone=GMT -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom $JAVA_OPTS -jar /app.jar
```

This is a snippet of my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  notification-service:
    hostname: notification-service
    container_name: notification-service
    image: com.company/notification-service:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - kafka-schema-registry
    ports:
      - 9810:9810
    volumes:
      - ./notification-service-application.yaml:/config/application.yml
```

Tried adding the ports 587:587 in docker-compose.yml but no success.

Comment: Which curl command did you use inside the container to validate that communication with the smtp server was OK? Please do not reply in a comment: edit your question and add this info.

Comment: Thanks for asking. Added the required info.

Comment: are you able to telnet to the mail server?

Comment: No... I am not able to do that even from my local machine... When I do telnet both from local as well as from docker, it gives me connection refused error where the same application is working locally...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 weeks of struggle, found out the issue was on my end only. The issue was SMTP proxy settings were missing. Once I configured SMTP proxy settings, I was getting read timed out error. So I increased the overall timeout settings to 20000 from 10000 and voila, I was able to send the emails to the recipient.

Making it an answer here just in case someone with similar problem lands to this page and this page might be able to help them.